# Modify gesture events(translate location) and programmatically send the modified event to another view

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I want to implement a modified version of Accessibility Zoom feature. In the zoomed in view, I want to be able to interact with the buttons which is present in the view below the Zoomed In View. [image: Accessibility Zoom] 
The following picture illustrates the issue. 
[image: picture below] 
I have

- 1. Parent View

     - a.  Child View 1
     - b. Child View 2

Gesture events are handled in *ChildView1*. When I get a dragGesture in *ChildView2* which is the zoomed in view, I want to be able to modify the touch points and pass the event to *ChildView1*. 
I've tried various approach:

- sendAction which can be called only on UIControls. (I was looking for Swift equivalent of `element.dispatchEvent(event)`-available in JavaScript)
- Check if Accessibility Zoom can be invoked programmatically (Not available)
- Modify UIGestureRecognizer object to change the `location(in view: UIView?) -> CGPoint` in *ChildView2* and invoke the selector for `dragGestureHandler` in *ChildView1*. I'm not sure of the side effects with this approach. 
   

  Can you share a good approach to solve this problem or re-implement Accessibility Zoom feature?

Comment: I have never tried the iOS Accessibility Zoom feature. But should it not work in nearly all situations? Why not in your app?

Comment: There seems to be no way to invoke it programmatically. I've watched nearly all WWDC videos for Accessibility. They haven't mentioned any API to invoke or modify ZOOM Controls.  To re-create the same functionality, there seems to be no direct way to recommended way to override modify the touch location for all gestures.